# Get the index of xml element according to its attribute / Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I need to find out the index (position) of XML element with certain attribute and namespace. In my XML there are more elements with the same name so only possible way to identify the right one is by its attribute.

This is sample of my XML document:

```
<mets:mets LABEL="Moderní pedagogika, 2002" TYPE="Monograph"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/"
    xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3"
    xmlns:ns3="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/"
    xmlns:ns5="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd http://www.loc.gov/METS/ http://www.loc.gov/standards/mets/mets.xsd http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3 http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-4.xsd http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink.xsd">
    <mets:metsHdr CREATEDATE="2012-12-05T07:42:22" LASTMODDATE="2012-12-05T07:42:22">
        <mets:agent ROLE="CREATOR" TYPE="ORGANIZATION">
            <mets:name>ABA001</mets:name>
        </mets:agent>
        <mets:agent ROLE="ARCHIVIST" TYPE="ORGANIZATION">
            <mets:name>ABA001</mets:name>
        </mets:agent>
    </mets:metsHdr>
    <mets:dmdSec ID="MODSMD_VOLUME_0001">
        .....   
    </mets:dmdSec>
    <mets:dmdSec ID="DCMD_VOLUME_0001"> 
        .....
    </mets:dmdSec>
</mets:mets>
```

Desired Index in this case is the index of this tag **<mets:dmdSec ID="MODSMD_VOLUME_0001">**

I have tried some solution regarding list(root).index(dmdSec) but without success since I am not able or do not know how to insert there details about attribute and namespace

Could someone help me with this

Comment: It's a bit unclear - you want to find its index position within what? For example, in your sample xml - what's the expected output? Also, can you edit the question and verify that you are using a well formed xml sample?

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Well, 

I am using tree=ET.parse("sample.xml"); root = tree.getroot()

And my aim is to get "1" as the index of this tag <mets:dmdSec ID="MODSMD_VOLUME_0001">.  So it is supposed to be within root tag which is <mets:mets .. >.
With this information I can use function insert(index, element) from Elementtree then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using the lxml.etree library for xml parsing - if not you may have to modify things a bit - but the principle is the same:

Simply use:

Edit:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.parse(r'path\to\your\file.xml')
int(root.xpath('count(//*[@ID="MODSMD_VOLUME_0001"]/preceding-sibling::*)+1'))
```

Output:
`2`.

Note that the position is `2` and not `1` - xpath counts from 1 (unlike python, which counts from 0). Your target is the second `<mets:dmdSec>` node within the root.

Comment: Yes, I use mentioned library, however I get an error anyway. Do you know what can be wrong?      position = int(root.xpath('count(//*[@ID="MODSMD_VOLUME_0001"]/preceding-sibling::*)+1'))
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'xpath'

Comment: @JonášKvět You are using a different library. You should use lxml. See edit.